# Can someone explain to me this C++ array?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr1[4];
    int arr2[4];
    for (int i = 0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        cin>>arr1[i];
        arr2[i]=arr1[i];
    }
    for(int j = 0;j<=4;j++)
    {
        cout<<arr1[j]<<" ";
        cout<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Outcome:

[image]

Can someone explain to me why `arr[0] = 5`? I cant figure it out.

Comment: You don't have `arr`, just have `arr1` and `arr2`.

Answer (score 2):

You accessed out of bounds when  `i=4`. `arr1` and `arr2` have only 4 elements. i.e. `arr1[0], arr1[1], arr1[2], arr1[3]` and `arr2[0], arr2[1], arr2[2], arr2[3]`.

Your compiler may assigned `arr1` just after `arr2`, and accidentaly `arr2 + 4` had the same address as `arr1`, so the access to `arr2[4]` wrote the value to `arr1[0]`.

Comment: well im trying to test to copy an array to another array can you suggest me ways on how to carry on with this, i deleted `arr2[i]=arr1[i]` and it display correctly now.

Comment: Just allocate enough memory to `arr1` and `arr2`.Say. `int arr1[5]; int arr2[5];`