# C++ arrays Writing a decoder

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
int arr1[5];
int arr2[5];
int arr3[5];

for (int i = 0;i<=4;i++)
{
    cin>>arr1[i];
    arr2[i]=arr1[i];

 }
 for(int j = 0;j<=4;j++)
 {
         cout<<arr1[j]<<" ";


  }

 cout<<endl;

 for(int x = 4;x>=0;x--)
 {

       cout<< arr2[x]<<" ";


       }

     for(int y=0;y<=4;y++)
       {
       cout<<"Enter numbers:";
    cin>>arr3[y];

    }


system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Well this is the code i have now, what i'am really making is a decoder

eg.

```
  1 = 5
    2 = 4
    3 = 3
    4 = 2
    5 = 1
    Input: 1 5 3 2 5
    Output:5 1 3 4 1
```

i cant seem to figure out how to make it. am i in the right track or am i doing something wrong? What i think is there is a base array , and i copy it to another array and reverse it. then the 3rd array will be the input.

after that it will display the decoded numbers.

Comment: Are you going to ask us for information [EVERY step of the way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32803610/can-someone-explain-to-me-this-c-array)? You can but you don't show ANY effort of trying to solve it yourself...

Comment: Two things: 1) you should learn to express your questions more clearly. I can infer what you want your code to do, but you should explain what the problem is. Do you get a compile-time error? A run-time crash? Does your code hang, or fail to give the correct answer? And 2) **simplify.** When you write code, start with something simple that works perfectly, then build up step by step. In this case, make sure your input routine works, then disable it and hard-code the input values. Write code to put values into the array, and read them out; when that works, transform them. Don't try all at once.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen sorry bro im new to coding and working step by step im up to arrays now but does not understand how the next lesson is i tried. i cannot use .compare here because its int data type. im searching for other ways

Comment: @Beta doing it manually now

Comment: also was able to reproduce it with a lot of if statements. but i'm really trying to make use of for loops

Comment: @Allahuakbar First: I'm not your `bro`... Second: You have a bad teacher if you cannot ask for help from him/her to help you understanding the `next lesson`... /ThereIsNoGod...